# What is the "Recovery" of Moriko Morioka after the series end?

Tags: recovery-of-an-mmo-junkie

The only "recovery" thing I see is that *both* (not just Moriko Morioka, but also Yuuta Sakurai) main characters have overcome their social difficulty.

I just watch eps 11. However I haven't see the mention on whether Moriko Morioka get a job or not. I wonder how she is making a living somehow. Because she stay home for too long (all the series), I think she might somehow run out of fund soon.

Did I miss something? About Morioka getting a job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Japanese title of *Recovery of an MMO Junkie* is ネト充のススメ (*Neto Juu no Susume*), which is closer in meaning to the subtitle of the English title, "Recommendation of the Wonderful Virtual Life." It is often the case that Japanese creators determine the official English title, and that the English title has a different, even incorrect, meaning.

However, it is possible that the English title would have been appropriate for the original webcomic, which was stopped before its intended completion due to the author's health.

> On June 30, 2018, it was announced that Comico has ended the manga due to Rin Kokuyō's failing health. Prior to this, Recovery of an MMO Junkie had been on a hiatus since 2015.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_of_an_MMO_Junkie)</sup>

I've read a bit of the comic, and it seemed that the anime diverged from it somewhat as well.

Comment: thanks, I will read the comic (did you mean Manga ?)

Comment: Thank you for point out "Recommendation of the Wonderful Virtual Life" was word-to-word translation of the anime name.

Comment: It's not exactly a word to word translation, as wonderful is definitely not in the title, but it's pretty close. It is also not a traditional manga, as it is published online only, and is full color, and not formatted like a regular manga. But I suppose it's manga in the sense of its a Japanese comic.